# Loader image does not hide when no data in jquery_datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Want to show and hide( #alertLoader ) Image with the status of Ajax request.
Currently its working when there is data in the table, but when there is no data it will not hide that loader image.

```
<?php

function GetVendorsTable(){
$('#alertLoader').show();

LoadTableInit();

$('#get-vendor-table').dataTable( {

            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "sAjaxSource": "activities.php?action=get-vendors-renewals&customerID="+<?php echo $_COOKIE['customerID']; ?>,
            "sAjaxDataProp": "result",
            "aaSorting": [],
            'iDisplayLength': 5,
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        "aTargets": [ 0 ],"mData": function (data) {
                        $('#alertLoader').hide();
                        var vendorName = data['vendorName'];
                        if(vendorName.length > 13){
                            var showVendorName = vendorName.substring(0,13);

                            return "<span class='tip' data-title='"+data['vendorName']+"'>"+showVendorName+"...</span>";
                        }else{
                            return "<span class='tip' data-title=''>"+data['vendorName']+"</span>";    
                        }
                    },"bSortable": true,
                    },
                    {
                      "aTargets": [ 1 ],"mData": function (data) {
                      var productName = data['productName'];
                      if(productName.length > 13){
                      var showProductName = productName.substring(0,13);

                       return "<span class='tip' data-title='"+data['productName']+"'>"+showProductName+"...</span>";
                    }else{
                        return "<span class='tip' data-title=''>"+data['productName']+"</span>";    
                    }

                    },"bSortable": true,
                    },
                    {
                      "aTargets": [ 2 ],"mData": function (data) {

                        return "<span class='tip' data-title=''>"+data['type']+"</span>";

                    },"bSortable": true,
                    },
                    {
                      "aTargets": [ 3 ],"mData": function (data) {

                  return "<span class='tip' data-title=''>"+numberWithCommasNoDecimal(data['duein'])+" days</span>";

                    },"bSortable": true,
                    },
                    {
                      "aTargets": [ 4 ],"mData": function (data) {
                        if(data['action'] != 0){
                            //var newaction = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="downloadFiles" onclick="downloadFiles(id)" id="'+data['action']+'">contract</a>';
                            //return "<span class='tip' data-title=''>"+newaction+"</span>";
                            var buttonSet = '<span style="font-size:20px;"><div class="btn-group pull-right"><button class="btn">Activity</button><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="downloadFiles" data-title="Download Contract" id="'+data['action']+'" >Download Contract</li></ul></div></span>';
                            $('.tip').tooltip();
                            return buttonSet;
                        }else{
                            return "<span class='tip' data-title=''></span>";
                        }

                    },"bSortable": true,
                                    }],
                    "oLanguage": {
                      "sLengthMenu": "Rows: _MENU_ ",
              "sSearch": "Search",
              "sEmptyTable": "No renewals and SLA found that meet alerting thresholds",
              "sZeroRecords": "No renewals and SLA found that meet alerting thresholds"
                    }

});
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

"sLoadingRecords": ""
add link of your image after colon
please put  at the end of code